# 関数内のifで定義された変数の処理について

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで関数内の `if` 内で定義された変数の処理に困っています。

以下のようなプログラムを作っています。

**目的:**
同階層フォルダ、もしくは1つ下の階層のフォルダの中にあるpngファイル名の変更

- TKinterのラジオボタンを使って、指定階層を【同階層】【1つ下の階層】と切り替え
- ウィジェット変数を使ってフォルダのパスを取得
- `/*.png` と `/*/*.png` をくっつけてglobでまとめて取得

初心者ゆえとりあえず思いついたものいろいろやってみたのですが、何も取得できず困ってます。

**問題のコード**
こちらのpathがおそらく取得できておらず空の状態になっています。
どのようにしたらいいでしょうか。
ラジオボタンの値取得などは正常に動作しているようですが、filelistを確認しても何も入っていませんでした。

```
def list_create():
    def get_file_path():
        path = ''
        folder_path = folder.get()
        if rename_type.get() == 1: 
            path = folder_path + '/*.png'
        elif rename_type.get() == 2: 
            path = folder_path + '/*/*.png'
        return path
    
    path = get_file_path()
    filelist = glob.glob(path)
```

下記に関係ありそうな部分を抽出しています。folderやrename_typeはこちらにあります。

```
#ウィジット変数
folder = tkinter.StringVar()
rename_type = tk.StringVar(value="ファイル名変更")

#フレームに入れる
frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)
part_rename_radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="個々", variable=rename_type, value=1)
export_rename_radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="まとめて", variable=rename_type, value=2)
```

Comment: 「同階層」とは何かについての情報(folder)の内容が設定されていないようですがそれが原因では？ それとも質問に書かれていないだけで設定はされているのでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございました！
記載漏れ失礼しました。 folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()を含んだ別の関数を用意しており、そちらから階層を指定しておりました。

Comment: 質問の際にはこれらのヘルプ記事を参考にしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> rename_type = tk.StringVar(value="ファイル名変更")
> ```

これは文字列型では無いでしょうか？
`if` 文の分岐では数値で判断しているのであてはまらず、`path` の中身が空のままになります

文字列で比較して分岐させるか、数値に変換して分岐させればいかがでしょうか

Comment: ありがとうございます！ご指摘とおり数値に変換してみたところ、思った通りの処理となりました。
 if int(rename_type.get()) == 1: 
            path = folder_path + '/*.png'
        elif int(rename_type.get()) == 2: 
            path = folder_path + '/*/*.png'
いろんなサイトを見て切り貼りしていたせいか気付きませんでした。勉強になりました。ありがとうございました！